# What is the best way to build a database from a MS Word document?

Tags: python, database, algorithm

Please advise me on how to approach this problem:

I have a sequential list of metadata in a document in MS Word. The basic idea is to create a Python algorithm to iterate over the information, retrieving just the name of the PROCESS, when is made a queue, from a database.

Example metadata:

> **Process:** Process Walker (1965)
>   **Exact reference:** Walker Process Equipment., Inc. v. Food Machinery Corp.
>
> **Link:** http://caselaw.lp.findlaw.com/scripts/getcase.pl?court=US&vol=382&invol=
>
> Type of procedure: Certiorari to the United States Court of Appeals for the Seventh Circuit.
>   Parties: Walker Process Equipment, Inc.
>
> **Sector:** Systems is ...
>
> **Start Date:** October 12-13 Arguedas, 1965
>   **Summary:** Food Machinery Company has initiated a process to stop or slow the entry of competitors through the use of a patent obtained by fraud. The case concerned a patent on "knee action swing diffusers" used in aeration equipment for sewage treatment systems, and the question was whether "the maintenance and enforcement of a patent obtained by fraud before the patent office" may be a basis for antitrust punishment.
>   Report of the evolution process: petitioner, in answer to respond...
>
> **Importance:** a) First case which established an analysis for the diagnosis of dispute…

There are about 200 pages containing the information above.

I have in mind the idea of implementing an algorithm in Python to be able to break this information sequence and try to store it in a web database (an open source application that I’m looking for) in order to allow for free consultations.

Comment: Do these always have the exact same sections, in the same order?  Is "Process: ..." always the first line?

Comment: @S.Lott.: I thought it was a perfectly reasonable question for SO.  Here's a data format, how can I rip the data to a database.

Comment: What version of Word is it? If 2007 (.docx) then you can look at the [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML)

Comment: @Orbling, the question is not precise enough to be answerable.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Hence why I asked for clarification rather than bumbling in with an answer. ;-)

Comment: Rolled back to original question (the answers make sense this way).  Please create a new question for your new questions, stop editing this one.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [AntiWord](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) for converting the document to plaintext, then grep and sed to convert to a format you can pipe into your script.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Word allow you to save documents in XML format. This can either be done by explicitly "saving as" and choosing XML, or unzipping a .docx file and parsing its XML. The XML formats are documented online depending on the version of Word: [2003 Office XML](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fe118952-3547-420a-a412-00a2662442d9&displaylang=en) or [2007/2010 Office Open XML](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).

Anything more powerful (e.g. requiring manipulation of the documents) requires interfacing with .NET ([MS Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en) or [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/).Words).